# Pytorch model with multi batchnorm1d layers get errors during inference - "expected 2D or 3D input (got 1D input)"

Tags: pytorch, inference, batchnorm

My model in pytorch with batchnorm1D is like this:

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, sequenceLength):
    super(Discriminator,self).__init__()
    self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(sequenceLength)
    self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(2*sequenceLength)
    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(sequenceLength, 2*sequenceLength)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(1, 1,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(1, 1,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.linear4 = nn.Linear(2*sequenceLength, 1)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU(0.01)
    self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

def forward(self, x):
    out = self.batchnorm1(x)
    out = self.linear1(out)
    out = self.relu(out)
    out = self.batchnorm2(out)
    out = out.unsqueeze(1)
    out = self.conv2(out)
    out = self.sigmoid(out)
    out = self.conv3(out)
    out = self.relu(out)
    out = out.squeeze()
    out = self.batchnorm2(out)
    out = self.linear4(out)
    out = self.sigmoid(out)
    return out
```

My inference code is like this:

```
Discriminator = torch.load('disc.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
Discriminator.eval()
embededSeq = Embedding.EmbedOne('sample data')
embededSeq = torch.tensor(embededSeq).float()
embededSeq = embededSeq.unsqueeze(0)
score = PosDiscriminator(embededSeq).detach().numpy()[0]
```

And I got the error message: "expected 2D or 3D input (got 1D input)" at the `out = self.batchnorm2(out)`  line in the model.
I wonder if is it caused by my previous line `out = out.squeeze()` or not?
However, the training code worked fine, only happen during the inference.

Could you please have a look and show me what's wrong?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Try embedding multiple sample data. Change "embededSeq = Embedding.EmbedOne('sample data')" this line

Comment: @core_not_dumped: Oh, that is my custom function, in which, receive a sequence and then return a digital vector. In this one, I want to evaluate my data one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this issue is caused by `out.squeeze`. In general you should avoid `out.squeeze()` without any dimension arguments because this removes all dimensions with a size of 1, resulting in a tensor with an indeterminate number of dimensions. Within a model the number of dimensions expected by each layer is pretty much always fixed so this is likely to cause problems.

Let your input be of shape `[batch_size,length]`. (As a side note some of these layers (e.g. `conv1D`) expect a channel dimension and all of these layers are compatible with a channel dimension, so you may want to add a channel dimension before input to the model rather than altering the number of dimensions within the model.). Here I use `length` as an arbitrary, changing length, not a fixed value.

- batchnorm1 output is of 2 dimensions `[batch_size,length]`
- linear1 otuput is of 2 dimensions `[batch_size,length]`
- unsqueeze output is of 3 dimensions `[batch_size,1,length]`
- conv2 and sigmoid outputs are of 3 dimensions `[batch_size,1,length]`
- conv3 and relu outputs are of 3 dimensions `[batch_size,1,length]`
- here you call out.squeeze(). In the training case, `batch_size` is greater than 1, so dimension 0 is not squeezed, and only dimension 1 is removed, producing a tensor of size `[batch_size,length]`.
- In the inference case, your `batch_size` is 1, so dimension 0 and 1 are BOTH squeezed. The result is a tensor of shape `[length]`.
- The next batchnorm layer expects either a 2D or 3D input `[batch_size,channels,length]` or `[batch_size, length]`. In the case where you have a batch of 1 (inference), the input violates this expectation, causing the error.

**FIX:**

You can fix this by specifying the dimension to squeeze:
`out = out.squeeze(1)`, which will always result in a tensor of shape `[batch_size,length]`.